# Codename one SpanLabel text does not occupying full width

Tags: codenameone

I'm using the SpanLabel Component, but on the screen the text content does not occupying the full width when text size is lower
Someone can help please?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the width isn't deterministic. The `SpanLabel` won't be able to reflow and at best will cause only its own `Container` to resize. There are two solutions:

- Deterministic hierarchy - this is generally best but not always possible
- Use `TextArea` - sometimes this works around the issue by reducing the hierarchy depth.

Deterministic layout means that the size of the elements is determined in a clear way by the hierarchy. E.g. BoxLayout.Y is deterministic on the X axis as it gives the components on the X axis all available space. `FlowLayout` isn't deterministic as it gives components their preferred size.

Some layouts can go back and forth and vary in determinism based on their axis.

This is important because when we layout the components we go from top down. So we go through the `Form` to its children asking each for their preferred size. If at this point the `SpanLabel` doesn't know its size it can give the wrong value and we can't really fix that later as we don't reflow the UI. Reflow would create a potential infinite loop and a performance problem at best.

We try to workaround some of this behavior by making a `revalidate()` call within `TextArea` but that has its limits. If the hierarchy is too deep the preferred size is already set and won't adapt. `SpanLabel` is just a `Container` with a `TextArea` and a `Label` (for the icon). So by only using a `TextArea` you'd slightly simplify the hierarchy and it sometimes might be enough. E.g.

```
TextArea t = new TextArea(myText);
t.setEditable(false);
t.setFocusable(false);
t.setUIID("Label");
```

Comment: Thanks Sir for the answer. I use the TextArea option, but the problem persists as the font size is small

Comment: Another important point is to make sure the font, padding & margin are identical in all states. If they differ our layout leaves space for one state and might look odd in a different state.